# Why RCA video doesn't provide colors

Tags: screen, output, openelec

When I use the HDMI with my Raspberry Pi, all is ok. But when I use RCA output on my television, the screen is black/white.

I have installed OpenELEC. I already changed of PERITEL-RCA adapter, I bought a AIO PERITEL-RCA cable, ... It seems that it isn't a wire problem.

My TV's colour encoding system is PAL (used in Europe), so I expect that I have to put 
`sdtv_mode=2` in `config.txt` (PAL=2). I cannot write on flash/`config.txt` because it's read only... I tried to mount it as a editable: `mount /flash -o remount, rw` but the output is

> "Mounting /flash on rw failed: No such file o directory"

but I see it when I `ls`.

Comment: Okay I reboot the raspberry and renew the mount. It takes effect and I was able to edit the config.txt. I add the line sdtv_mode=2" an saved it (trough vi).Then I reboot and magic, colors appears !

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it in two days, when it becomes possible for you to do so.

Comment: try useing your pc to change config.txt it will show up as a text file in windows be sure not to format it

Comment: Agree with @AndrejaKo, you should put your solution as an answer and accept the answer.  People go looking for unanswered questions trying to help.  Leaving solved items hanging makes it more difficult to find the real unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

'sdtv_mode=2' Sets PAL mode by default, you can switch by the numbers (1-4) of the keyboard (tested with NOOBS) when boot first time, NTSC is the default mode

Here's a very usefull Wiki with the possible modes you can use in the config.txt

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/config.txt/info